# How to serve staticfiles from docker django app to hosted nginx

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

My goal is to serve the staticfiles to nginx on ubuntu from a docker django app container without using docker nginx

I setup the reverse proxy to django all works fine in dev mode but when i turn Debug to False nginx doesn't recognize the staticfiles path
 [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt7RD.png)

Here's my dockerfile for django app

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]
CMD ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And here's my nginx config

```
upstream django { 
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
 } 
 server {
    server_name django.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 8000;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {    
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 1000;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1000;
        proxy_send_timeout 1000; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#runserver) say you shouldn’t use `runserver` in production. Switch to something like gunicorn instead.

Comment: You could use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/index.html#) to serve the static files, then you won’t have to configure nginx.

Comment: I just started learning django, thank you i'll look into them

Answer (score 1):

To have NGINX serve your staticfiles, your config needs to be edited. How do you expect nginx to find your files otherwise?

Luckily, it's a simple edit. :)

```
upstream django { 
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
 } 
 server {
    server_name django.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 8000;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    
    location /static {
        alias /PATH/TO/STATIC_FILES;
    }

    location / {    
        proxy_pass http://django;
        ...
    }
}
```

Don't forget to configure your static root, and run:

```
py manage.py collectstatic
```

This will make sure Django's default CSS/JS is included in your staticfiles.

When `DEBUG=True`, your staticfiles will be served by Django. This is not good, and can lead to some serious perfomance and security problems.

##### Edit:

Alternatively, have a look at Django-Whitenoise. It's great for serving staticfiles.

http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: im runing nginx on ubuntu and django on a docker container
so if i point my nginx to /static it will look to local path ( on the ubuntu server not on the django container )
i configured my static root and static url 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/django/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads/')

Comment: You're using docker. Copy the staticfiles on each compose? Staticfiles are static. They /should/ not change, so it shouldn't matter too much. You can even skip setting the staticfiles settings in settings.py after you've collectstatic. Just have nginx serve it. You still need the `STATIC_URL`, otherwise Django cannot find your files. @AyoubRabeh

Comment: i copied them to my host server and it works fine now.
i hope that it doesn't matter :D

Comment: @AyoubRabeh It really doesn't. As long as you keep the directories/files the same. Have a great day. Added an alternative for you in case you'd like more options.